# Object property with the value of null is being treated as ''

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I have a set of code where I retrieve data from the database using eloquent

Controller

```
       $display_tickets = ManualTicket::select('*')
            ->with('user')
            ->with('initiator')
            ->with('manual_ticket_log')
            ->where(function ($checkClients) use($target_client_id){
                $checkClients->whereHas('user', function ($checkClient) use($target_client_id){
                    $checkClient->where('client_id', '=', $target_client_id);
                })
                ->orWhereHas('initiator', function ($checkClient2) use($target_client_id){
                    $checkClient2->where('client_id', '=', $target_client_id);
                });
            })
            ->whereBetween('manual_tickets.created_at', [$start_date->toDateString(), $end_date->addDays(1)->toDateString()])
            ->orderBy("manual_tickets.created_at", "desc")->get();
```

The variable is then returned to the blade file

```
  return view('ticket-dashboard/dashboard', compact('display_tickets'));
```

On the blade file, for each ticket that I receive I am displaying them in a table. However, when the property $display_tickets['ticket_flow_id'] is null, it is being regarded as ' ' on the blade file when it actually holds the value of null. Why is that???

```
@foreach($display_tickets as $p)
<table>
<th> ticket flow id </th>
<tr>
<td>
        <script type="application/javascript">
                console.log('{{$p['ticket_flow_id']}}');
                var typee = '{{$p['ticket_flow_id']}}';
                console.log(typeof typee);
         </script>
</td>
```

[image]

Controller code

```
 error_log(json_encode($display_tickets));
 error_log("??salkag");
 error_log(json_encode($display_tickets->ticket_flow_id));
 error_log(gettype($display_tickets->ticket_flow_id));
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Long shot but have you tried this :

```
{!! $p['ticket_flow_id'] !!}
```

By default `{{}}` passes the string through PHPs `htmlspecialchars` you might get your expected result although opens it up to XSS

Comment: As an aside laravel allows you to pass an array to `with()` so your code could be simplified to : 

`->with(['user', 'initiator', 'manual_ticket_log']);`

Comment: thanks for the timely response. Does it mean that the null value is being converted to an empty string when i try to save the ticket flow id property into a data attribute of <td>